# Is it possible to dim the entire iPhone screen while keeping one view on top?

Tags: iphone, uikit

I have a UITabbar-based iphone app with a NavigationController bar on the top.  I also have a logout view that I present on top, while dimming the background.  You can see here:  http://d.pr/i/XH6x

However, the dimmed background does not cover the UINavigationBar on top nor the UITabbar on the bottom.  How can I dim the entire screen, while keeping the LogoutView on top?

Right now, I'm doing the dimmed view with this code:

```
UIView *dimView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.collectionView.frame];
dimView.tag = kDimView;
dimView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
dimView.alpha = 0.7;
[self.view addSubview:dimView];
```

Thank you!

EDIT:  I should mention that this is a UITabBarController based application, with UInavigationControllers for each of the 3 tabs.

Comment: why is the frame of collection view

Comment: Ah yes, sorry that should be self.view, but it's still wont cover both the Navbar and Tabbar.

Comment: Simply add that to window

Comment: Thank you.  This worked:     UIView *dimView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].frame];
    dimView.tag = kDimView;
    dimView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    dimView.alpha = 0.0;
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:dimView];

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
  UIWindow* mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

 dimView.frame = CGRectMake(00, 00,mainWindow.frame.size.width , mainWindow.frame.size.height);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to dim the view, where your tabbar and navigation bar lies.

For example, there is one UIViewController named `RootViewController`, which contains your `UITabbarController` and `UINavigationController`.

So try to set alpha value for that view, and then do add subview normally, as you are doing.